# Rendering Geojson is very unstable

Tags: json, openlayers-3

While moving from Openlayers-2.11 to ol3, I have experienced a strange problem. The geojson file which is dynamical extracted from a mysql database is sometimes rendered, sometimes not. The extraction is done via a PHP script. Please [see this link](http://yachtguard.no/yg/utils/retriveData.php) for a live example.
I have run the file through several online json validators, but all of them came up with "valid json" as result. Since the geojson file is dynamic, my first thought was that there might be some illegal characters hidden in the file, but I am not able to find any. The ol3 implementation is straight forward;

```
var image = new ol.style.Circle({
  radius: 5,
  fill: null,
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'red', width: 1})
});

var styles = {
 'Point': [new ol.style.Style({image: image})]
};

var styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
  return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
};  

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
                url: '../../../../yg/utils/retriveData.php',
                projection: 'EPSG:3857'
            }),
    style: styleFunction
});
```

I have run other static json files through the same code without hassle. The problem seems to be only with this dynamic file.

May I kindly ask for guidelines on what could be the best debugging strategy in this case.

The PHP script looks like this;

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "xxxxxxxx", "1234", "xxxxx");

$sql = 'SET names utf8';

$rs = $conn->query($sql);

if (!$rs) {
  echo 'An SQL error occured.\n';
  exit;
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM extract_data';

# Try query or error
$rs = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$rs) {
   echo 'An SQL error occured.\n';
exit;
}

# Build GeoJSON feature collection array
$geojson = array(
   'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
   'features'  => array()
);

# Loop through rows to build feature arrays
while ($row = $rs->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $properties = $row;
   # Remove x and y fields from properties (optional)
   unset($properties['lat']);
   unset($properties['lon']);
   $feature = array(
    'type' => 'Feature',
    'geometry' => array(
        'type' => 'Point',
        'coordinates' => array(
            $row['lon'],
            $row['lat']
        )
    ),
    'properties' => $properties
);
# Add feature arrays to feature collection array
array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
}

header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode($geojson, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

$conn = NULL;
?>
```

Comment: probably an asynchronous problem. Have you noticed if bigger is your json, more often it is not rendered?

Comment: Please, limit your php to 10 features, to easier debugging.

Comment: You seem to be using an old version of ol3. What version are you on?

Comment: @Alvin Lindstam - I'm on v3.4.0 since I'm following the guidelines in the "The book of OpenLayers 3" (https://leanpub.com/thebookofopenlayers3)

Comment: @stenhh ol3 is constantly evolving, the latest release is 3.10.1 (and ol.source.GeoJSON has been removed). I would recommend using a later version if possible.

Comment: @Jonatas Walker - thanks for giving me the idea of limiting the amount of data. The problem was actually in my decoding algorithm before storing the information in the database. My sanity check on the LAT/LON values didn't do its job - LAT values greater than 90 passed through the filter and created the mess. Thanks.

Comment: @Jonatas Walker: It is, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be related to your problem but I found something wrong in your code

You are not calling `styleFunction` correctly and you are not passing its`feature` and `resolution` parameters.

You could try that for debugging:

```
var styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
  return styles['Point']; //for debugging
};  

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
                url: '../../../../yg/utils/retriveData.php',
                projection: 'EPSG:3857'
            }),
    style: styleFunction()
});
```

Other thing, from [OL3 Documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/examples/vector-layer.html), you should create your vector layer from geojson like this:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
                url: '../../../../yg/utils/retriveData.php',
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                projection: 'EPSG:3857'
            }),
    style: styleFunction()
});
```